# angular conditional ng-hide with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I wish to only show a delete button for tasks in which the creator of the task email is equal to the current user. For some reason I can't get the conditional function working with ng-show.
I have tried multiple methods to no success.

```
    <li ng-repeat="(key, challenge) in challenges| orderBy: '-date'">
         <!--<button ng-show="{{challenge.email}}=={{currentUser.email}}" class="btn btn-delete tooltip" ng-click="deleteChallenge(key)">-->
                <button ng-show="deletePermission(challenge.email)" class="btn btn-delete tooltip" ng-click="deleteChallenge(key)">
                    <span>Delete this challenge</span>
                </button>
     <div class="info"><h2>{{challenge.name}}</h2> Creator: {{challenge.owner}} {{challenge.email}} {{currentUser.email}}
<!--        <span class="date">by: {{message.owner}}</span> <br>-->
        <div class="date">{{challenge.date| date: "MMM d, yy, h:mm a"}}</div>
     </div> 
    </li>
```

There is also this javascript function to try to return true with equal to the rootscope currentUser. Neither of these work.

```
    $scope.deletePermission(value)
    if(value==$rootScope.currentUser.email)
      //  if(value==$scope.challenge.email)
                    return true;
    else
                    return false;
```

Solution:

haha, in my database it wasn't challenge.email attribute, but ownerEmail. Thanks a ton of the help at least i know that brackets weren't needed.

```
    <button ng-show="challenge.ownerEmail == currentUser.email" class="btn btn-delete tooltip" ng-click="deleteChallenge(key)">
  <span>Delete this challenge</span>
</button>
        <button ng-show="deletePermission(challenge.ownerEmail)" class="btn btn-delete tooltip" ng-click="deleteChallenge(key)">
            <span>Delete this challenge</span>
        </button>
```

Either one of these works. The deletePermission function in the javascript controller also needed a few adjustments. Thanks streetturtle! (is there a way to highlight your name?)

Comment: can you make a code example in plunker or something? It's easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

Expression should be following:

```
<button ng-show="challenge.email == currentUser.email" class="btn btn-delete tooltip" ng-click="deleteChallenge(key)">
  <span>Delete this challenge</span>
</button>
```

There is no need in curly brackets because you're already in `ng-show`.

Regarding the function - you have wrongly defined it, should be something like:

```
$scope.deletePermission = function(value){
  if(value==$rootScope.currentUser.email)
    return true;
  else 
    return false;
}
```

Or even better:

```
$scope.deletePermission = function(value){
  return (value==$rootScope.currentUser.email);
}
```